# delete empty values in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

My code is as follows:

```
new_dict = {k: v for k,v in d.items() if v != None}
```

I need to delete the empty values that appear as `''` in my dictionary.

I currently get the output:

```
'000B4662348C35B4': ['000B4662348C35B4', '', '', '', '', '', '2938717381', '5286676508', '7818174481', '2938717381', '4110479734', '9894624226', '9827417465', '9907632031', '2941365751', '1220277655', '7455720881', '88810260', '8441033464', '3992507902', '8464607083', '1201527184', '2861935553', '4110479734', '5789253700', '2637281600', '5603666228', '9126320955', '2431085055', '8833906919', '1565530436', '8340343124', '2029932640', '6334249086'],
```

this is just a little bit of the output but you should get the idea.
I just want the `''` removed.

so far I have tried:

```
new_dict = {k: v for k,v in d.items() if v != ''}
new_dict = {k: v for k,v in d.items() if v}
```

all of those still print the same output.

Comment: Can you post your input? From the output you posted I'm assuming, that value is a list of strings, so `v != None` won't work. You'll have to iterate each of the lists.

Comment: Those aren't dictionary values, they're elements of the list.

Comment: You should be deleting values from the list which is the dictionary value behind the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use list comprehension on dictionary values where you will filter-out empty elements:

```
d = {'000B4662348C35B4': ['000B4662348C35B4', '', '', '', '', '', '2938717381', '5286676508', '7818174481', '2938717381', '4110479734', '9894624226', '9827417465', '9907632031', '2941365751', '1220277655', '7455720881', '88810260', '8441033464', '3992507902', '8464607083', '1201527184', '2861935553', '4110479734', '5789253700', '2637281600', '5603666228', '9126320955', '2431085055', '8833906919', '1565530436', '8340343124', '2029932640', '6334249086']}

d = {k: [i for i in v if i] for k, v in d.items()}
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'000B4662348C35B4': ['000B4662348C35B4', '2938717381', '5286676508', '7818174481', '2938717381', '4110479734', '9894624226', '9827417465', '9907632031', '2941365751', '1220277655', '7455720881', '88810260', '8441033464', '3992507902', '8464607083', '1201527184', '2861935553', '4110479734', '5789253700', '2637281600', '5603666228', '9126320955', '2431085055', '8833906919', '1565530436', '8340343124', '2029932640', '6334249086']}
```

Note:

```
{k: v for k,v in d.items() if v != ''}
```

will just filter-out dictionary values that aren't equal to `''`, but your dictionary values are lists.

---

EDIT: Without list and dict-comprehensions:

```
out = {}
for k, v in d.items():
    tmp = []
    for i in v:
        if i != "":
            tmp.append(i)
    out[k] = tmp

print(out)
```

Comment: I was just wondering if you knew the code without the one-liner? I just realized I can't use it which is negating what I asked in my question. I'm trying to deconstruct it : ```for k,v in d.items():
            for i in v:
                if i != '':
                    test[k] = v``` but that just prints out the same thing with the empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

### Try the following example

```
d = {'000B4662348C35B4': ['000B4662348C35B4', '', '', '', '', '', '2938717381', '5286676508', '7818174481', '2938717381', '4110479734', '9894624226', '9827417465', '9907632031', '2941365751', '1220277655', '7455720881', '88810260', '8441033464', '3992507902', '8464607083', '1201527184', '2861935553', '4110479734', '5789253700', '2637281600', '5603666228', '9126320955', '2431085055', '8833906919', '1565530436', '8340343124', '2029932640', '6334249086']}
new_dict = {k: [i for i in v if i != ''] for k,v in d.items()}
print(new_dict)
```

### Explanation

since the `v` is the list you can't check if the list is empty because it will always return `true` though you have to iterate on its elements to remove those empty ones like the above example

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to work with arbitrarily nested lists and dicts, I'd do it via a recursive function:

```
>>> def remove_falsy_recursive(obj):
...     """Recursively remove all falsy values from a nested dict/list."""
...     if isinstance(obj, dict):
...         return {k: remove_falsy_recursive(v) for k, v in obj.items() if v}
...     if isinstance(obj, list):
...         return [remove_falsy_recursive(i) for i in obj if i]
...     return obj
...
>>> remove_falsy_recursive({'foo': ['bar', '', 'ola', ''], 'bar': False})
{'foo': ['bar', 'ola']}
```

Note that this uses the Python concept of "falsiness", which includes empty strings, `None`s, zeroes, etc.  If your requirement for "empty" values doesn't quite match that, adjust as needed.

This is IMO easier to understand than a single nested comprehension, it's a lot more resilient to changes in the structure of the input, and it's fairly easy to extend it to handle other types or conditions.